# Laravel Generate Migration from existing Model

Tags: laravel, model, migration

How can I create migration file from existing model in Laravel or model from existing migration?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations
read this documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the model, just create a model, there isn't anything special, just make sure to set the `$table` if not following convention.

For generating migrations from an existing Database schema there is a package:

[Xethron - Laravel Migration Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)

Answer (score 9):

To create a table for a existing Model, you just have to run below command,

```
php artisan make:migration table_name
```

and, go to the `database -> migration -> date_with-table_name`

inside `up()`, type your table name and fields that you want to add, something like belowa;

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('field_2');
    $table->string('field_3');
    $table->string('field_4');
    $table->date('field_5');
    $table->string('field_6');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

[read more here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

Answer (score 3):

Model and migration are merely connected through naming convention. Models and migrations are created separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
 php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

your Model name will be User and the table name will be users